# Commenting out `alert` stops function from executing

Tags: javascript, function, alert

I have this code which executes when text is pasted into an input field. It works perfectly when I have the `alert` included (ie `makeCode()` is excecuted), but when I comment out the `alert` then `makeCode()` is no longer executed. Thoughts?

```
const handleInputPaste = ev => {
    //alert("hi");
    makeCode();
}

inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('paste', handleInputPaste)
})
```

Comment: Please show more code. Sounds like a timing issue. Click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]. Also consider delegation to the nearest static container and perhaps use `input` event instead

Comment: I may be talking nonsense, but I believe that alert ends up giving you time to load some important information for `makeCode()`